# Change the default file encoding in Windows 10 operating system

Tags: java, windows

I would like to change the default file encoding scheme of my windows system.

For example, when I call the property 'file.encoding', in Java it should reflect.

String fileEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");

Can any one tell me, how to change the default file encoding scheme at system level.

Comment: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7) tells that it isn't possible.

Comment: Note that `file.encoding` is the JVM's guess at the system's encoding and the very concept cannot really work, as on Windows that's always a non-Unicode encoding. It's also fairly undocumented and some posts around the web seem to imply that it doesn't necessarily match the user's set legacy codepage.